# Defining < for STL sort algorithm - operator overload, functor or standalone function?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, operator-overloading, functor

I have a stl::list containing Widget class objects. They need to be sorted according to two members in the Widget class.

For the sorting to work, a less-than comparator comparing two Widget objects must be defined. There seems to be a myriad of ways to do it. From what I can gather, one can either:

a. Define a comparison operator overload in the class:

```
bool Widget::operator< (const Widget &rhs) const
```

b. Define a standalone function taking two Widgets:

```
bool operator<(const Widget& lhs, const Widget& rhs);
```

And then make the Widget class a friend of it:

```
class Widget {
    // Various class definitions ...
    friend bool operator<(const Widget& lhs, const Widget& rhs);
};
```

c. Define a functor and then include it as a parameter when calling the sort function:

```
class Widget_Less :
public binary_function<Widget, Widget, bool> { 
    bool operator()(const Widget &lhs, const Widget& rhs) const;
};
```

Does anybody know which method is better? In particular I am interested to know if I should do 1 or 2. I searched the book Effective STL by Scott Meyer but unfortunately it does not have anything to say about this.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Looks like I missed item 46 of Effective STL. It says prefer functors to member functions as it can be inlined more easily.

Comment: I get that doing option A (a member function of the class) is a little easier. But what are you supposed to compare the argument to? A simple `return (x<y)` where y is the argument doesn't work...at least not for me, I get a seg fault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are only comparing two Widgets to each other, use a member `operator <`.  If you are comparing Widget to something else, define a global `operator <` (the two parameter version, optionally a friend of the Widget class but that is a separate issue.

Functor you really only want if you are doing something a little less orthodox.  Choose a functor if a "less than" comparison doesn't make sense in the context of widgets.  In that case, having `operator <` could be confusing.  Of course, functors still have to provide an ordering, but just because it is an ordering doesn't really mean it is a "less than" operation.  (Example, sorting states by population is probably better for a functor than an `operator <`.

Comment: +1. The **most important** rule of operator overloading is don't do it if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

a. b. Comparison operator for two Widgets is not intuitive thing as for me. Now I can't see what it can do.
Also if this function is not intuitive once you will need one new comparison operator, what you can do in this case?

I prefer functor.

Comment: Whether or not it is intuitive is irrelevant, and applies to any method of defining the comparator. All you need is a comparison that is sound.

Comment: I meant that some entities could be compared (float, int, string, complex numbers, long numbers..) by anyone, some entities not - in this case I'm using compare function/functor e.g. WidgetByXCoordinateComparator, WidgetByNameComparator, etc.

Comment: In general it is good practice to use operator overloading only when they are intuitive understandable by all people.

Answer (score 1):

They should all be the same in terms of performance, but there are other differences between them:

- The first two save you having to explicitly specify the comparator, and can be used easily with other operations, possibly poorly defined ones that don't allow explicit specification of a comparator.
- Only the functor allows additional data for the comparison. For example, if you were comparing `int`s, you could create a comparison that compares their distance from a third point, P, which would be a member of the functor instance.
- Functors are generally less easy to read (to those not familiar with C++).

Note, you don't need to inherit `binary_operator` for it to work, although it does give you some nice `typedef`s.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not realise that the functor does you need binary_operator to work - anyway I always included it in my programs anyway. Your comment about performance may not be correct if Effective STL item 46 is correct (functions in the functors can be inlined).

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes, a. and b. are the same. So the real question is, when to use a/b and when to use c.

The answer is: use a or b if "less than" makes sense for your object in unequivocal terms. If your class is a number, use `<`.

If "less than" makes no sense in the context of your class, then please don't overload "operator<" for your class. It will confuse users. Use c. instead, and either make it a nested class or typedef it inside your class so you can write it as `Widget::Compare`.