# C++ How to use a map

Tags: c++

Im quite a noob at c++ so I hope this question isn't too obvious.

I'm currently creating a voxel engine. Now I need to get a chunk on a specified XYZ location.

The chunk management class has a `vector<Chunk*> loadedChunks`.

I can't use the index location of the vector because once I move the character it will change positions because old chunks will be removed and new chunks will be added.

In Java I would've used an `HashMap<Point3D, Chunk>` so I've googled to see if c++ has something like that an I found that there is a class called map.

So I tried to use the map and used a class called Point3D that contains the x,y,z locations of the chunk but this gave me an error because I'm using a chunk* an point3D wasn't a pointer. I can't save the Point3D as a pointer because then I still can't get the location by xyz.

Now the question is, is there a way to use the map like this or is there maybe a better way to get the chunk at x,y,z or do I have to stick with the slowest loop that loops through all the chunks and returns the chunk that has equal x,y,z?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ChunkManager.h
...
map<Point3D, Chunk*> loadedChunks;
....

ChunkManager.cpp

void ChunkManager::addChunk(Chunk* chunk){
    loadedChunks.insert(make_pair(Point3D(chunk->x, chunk->y, chunk->z), chunk));

    Chunk* c = loadedChunks[Point3D(chunk->x, chunk->y, chunk->z)];
}

Chunk* ChunkManager::getChunkAt(int x, int y, int z){
    return loadedChunks[Point3D(chunk->x, chunk->y, chunk->z)];
}

void ChunkManager::render(Renderer& renderer){
    for(auto iterator = loadedChunks.begin(); iterator != loadedChunks.end(); iterator++){
        iterator->second->render(renderer);
    }
}

void ChunkManager::update(double delta){
    for(auto iterator = loadedChunks.begin(); iterator != loadedChunks.end(); iterator++){
        iterator->second->update(delta);
    }
}

Point3D:

class Point3D
{
public:
    Point3D(int x, int y, int z);
    int x, y, z;
    bool operator< (const Point3D &rhs) const;
};

bool Point3D::operator< (const Point3D &rhs) const {
return x < rhs.x || ( x == rhs.x && ( y < rhs.y || ( y == rhs.y && z < rhs.z)));
}
```

I've just added the operator< and now its working.

```
return x < rhs.x || ( x == rhs.x && ( y < rhs.y || ( y == rhs.y && z < rhs.z)));
```

Comment: Show the code and the error - an error caused by 'point3d not begin a pointer' seems unlikely. You should avoid raw pointers in C++ code.

Comment: What is the definition of Point3D? Does it use integer or floating point coordinates? Also, how often do you need to insert items into the map or remove them from it?

Comment: I've added the point3D header.

I need to insert a lot of items when starting and then only when the character moves over a border of a chunk.

So you could say quite a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a map like you want. Nothing to do with pointers.... you have other (possibly conceptual) problems there.

but you create a `std::map<Point3d, Chunk*> loadedChunks;`

add values with `loadedChunks.insert(std::make_pair(my_point3d, my_chunk_ptr));`

read them using find() or operator[] - they have slightly different behaviour (op[] will return a reference to something, adding a new entry if it didn't already exist, find will return a pair, a bool to say the entry existed or not and an iterator to the entry).

your Point3d class will need to have an operator< at least that the map can use to determine where in the map to put the Point3d.

If you think this will not perform well (a map is implemented as a tree structure) then you can use boost, they have an [unordered_map class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/unordered.html) that uses a hash table instead.

One thing I would potentially recommend is to use unique_ptr<> or shared_ptr<> for your chunk pointers though. These will help prevent leaks if you don't manage the pointer properly.

Comment: Ah I understand the error now.

So how would this operator< work in the point3d class?

Should I check if x<x2 && y<y2 && z<z2?

Comment: [Try this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436705/defining-for-stl-sort-algorithm-operator-overload-functor-or-standalone-fun) for code sample and discussion on which option is best to use.

Comment: unordered_map is also part of STL since c++11